# Android app slowing down and crashing

Tags: android, android-studio, mpandroidchart

I created an app in android studio that plots a graph(using mp android chart) from the data received from a source. Here's the problem: when I try to plot the data at high frequencies (like 150hz plus) the app slows down and then crashes. At lower frequencies it can keep plotting for as long as I like so I know its not running out of memory. Maybe it needs a minimum amount of time to clear its memory? Is their anything I can do that can help me clear the memory when I want?

Comment: Why do you need 150hz? The android best practices says to aim for 60hz (http://developer.android.com/training/testing/performance.html). Typically, users can't tell the difference if faster than that.

Comment: Because I'm building an oscilloscope app that shows electric waveforms. It needs rates of over 200 hz ideally.

Comment: Just because your data is sampled at 200hz doesn't mean you need to update the UI at 200hz. Basically, instead of adding each individual point every UI update at 200hz, add the next 7 points at 30hz (or whatever you need).

Answer (score -1):

You can call `System.gc()` manually to invoke garbage collection, but Android will still kick in a GC when you are running out of memory.

Note that a garbage collection can easily take 100ms and when you have a refresh rate of 150hz you only have 1000/150 = 6.667 ms for your calculations together with garbage collection. So your first step should probably be to check your object allocations and try to minimize those. (in fact, in your methods which are called every frame you should have no object allocations at all)